# C# Access tags properties by HtmlElement

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control, innerhtml, getattribute

There is an html like:

```
<div id="instance" style="color:red;display:block;  .... bila bila">
   <h2>some text</h2>
</div>
```

I wanna access style of div via this code;

```
foreach (HtmlElement link in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
{
   if (link.GetAttribute("id").ToString() == "instance")
   {
      MessageBox.Show(link.innerhtml);
   }
}
```

But *link.innerhtml* gives me the inside of div tag, not div's own. Output text of Messag.Box is:

```
<h2>some text</h2>
```

I also tried this too:

```
MessageBox.Show(link.GetAttribute("style"));
```

but it didnt work.

How to access div properties via same div's id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use something like this:

`MessageBox.Show(link.OuterHtml);`

Comment: it works. thaks. additionally can we access directly in style text?

Comment: @AliCAKIL For getting list of styles from html element use Style Property like this: link.Style

Anyway here's the complete description of HtmlElement class:

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx)